# What is communicating 'auto my_var =' vs. 'auto& my_var ='?

Tags: c++, c++17, auto

What is the difference between writing:

```
auto my_var = [expression];
```

and

```
auto& my_var = [expression];
```

A) What is being communicated ?

B) Is the first version guaranteed to be a copy ? (when, when not ?)

C) When should you use the second 'auto&' ?

**Update:**

One example is when expression evaluates to a reference:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    auto  ints = std::vector{-1};

    auto front_int = ints.front();//front returns a reference, but 'auto' doesn't reflect that (giving us a copy instead)
    front_int = 0;

    return ints.front();//returns '-1', we didn't update the vector
}
```

This may not seem intuitive at first (while it makes sense if you try to look at the broader picture). To 'fix', we need to use `auto&` version, **- but why is that exactly ?**

Comment: This looks like an exam question or a book assignment, which you really should try to solve yourself (by reading your books and class notes). As a hint though: What do you know about *references*?

Comment: `auto& my_var` is a reference; `auto my_var` is not. Do you know what references are?

Comment: How does the "not a pointer" postscript matter? References to pointers work like references to ints; you can change the pointer through a reference.

Comment: I checked existing questions to see if it's a duplicate, but this indeed seems like a unique question. It may be a bit basic, but that is not an objection. I can see how it is useful to C++ beginners. I just removed the postscript, as it would probably only add confusion for beginners. Pointers are objects too, and unless specifically specified otherwise (i.e. arithmetic) they have the normal object behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This may seem basic and I should have written that this question came up during a code review and I thought it appropriate enough to get some trackion in here. It may not seem clear for beginners what the consequences is.

Comment: Initially it seemed like your question was "what is the difference between `auto` and `auto&`?" Now it seems like your question is "why is value the default instead of reference?" Can you clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: If `auto` could capture by reference, how would you create an `auto` copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is being communicated ?

The type of `my_var` is being communicated. `my_var` is a variable that is being declared. More specifically, the ampersand (or lack thereof) communicates whether the type is a reference or not.

> is the first version guareenteed to be a copy ?

It is guaranteed to be a distinct object.

It is not guaranteed to copy however. That depends on the expression. If it is a prvalue, then there will not be a copy since C++17; The variable will be initialised by the expression directly. Otherwise there is a copy (or move if the type has a move constructor and if the expression is an xvalue or if it is prvalue prior to C++17) as far as the abstract machine is concerned. But that copy / move may be elided in practice in some cases.

An example demonstrating lack of any copying. Following program is well-formed in C++17:

```
struct not_opyable_nor_movable {
    not_opyable_nor_movable()                          = default;
    not_opyable_nor_movable(not_opyable_nor_movable&)  = delete;
    not_opyable_nor_movable(not_opyable_nor_movable&&) = delete;
};

not_opyable_nor_movable function() {
    return {};
}

int main() {
    auto my_var = function();
}
```

> when should you use the second 'auto&' ?

When you want to declare an lvalue reference. Example:

```
int foo{};
auto& myvar = foo;
myvar = 42; // foo is now 42
```

> we need to use auto& version, -**but why is that exactly** ?

Because it seems that you want to make changes to the object referred by the result of the function call. To do that, you must make the modification through a reference. The ampersand is used to declare a reference.

Comment: You might want to make explicit what happens in the case of a prvalue, if not a copy. (a move, but only if there is a move ctor, else you still get a copy of the prvalue).

Comment: @MSalters added explanation.

Comment: @eerorika care to expand on the last answer, perhaps by example ? (atm. it's somewhat like stating the obvious)

Comment: @darune added an example.